# How can I add a delay to a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read the docs, and know that `.delay()` is the easiest method to add a delay to a function.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

I want to create a 10sec delay between replacing the HTML of an element twice:

```
 $('.access-details').html('text-1').delay(10000).html('text2');
```

However, this jumps instantly to `text-2` without any delay. What am I doing wrong?

JS Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/8PpnB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to queue it for the delay to work

```
$('.access-details').html('text-1').delay(10000).queue(function () {
    $(this).html('text2')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qgR6c/)

---

Or use a plain old setTimeout()

```
$('.access-details').html('text-1');
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.access-details').html('text-2')
}, 2500)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/svj7r/)

Answer (score 1):

**The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects.**

It can't apply to `.html()` method.

If you want to use `.delay()`, then you could do like below:

```
$('.access-details').show(0, function() {
  $(this).html('text1')
}).delay(10000).show(0, function() {
  $(this).html('text2')
});
```

***[Check the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/8PpnB/1/)***

Else you have to use the JavaScript's native `setTimeout` function.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
 $('.access-details').html('text-1').hide().show(1000,function() {
   $(this).html('text2');
 });
```